# Set Autolock programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, ipod-touch

How to set auto lock my iphone/ipad/ipod screen programmatically after some time delay?

Comment: If you know please tell me, If you share your knowledge it will definitely increase and may help full to some  one like me....Isn't it???

Comment: It is possible but that's strictly private API. What do you need it for?

Comment: For my alarm application that I am creating, when I set the auto lock , the screen should be locked after the delay that is specified may be 5, 10 or 15 minutes. If set never den the screen will never be locked. So in short I need the function so that I can implement in proper manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"idleTimerDisabled"  is the answer for the same, put it in the time and make iphone lock or unlock as per the requirements. Yes I got it.....

Comment: `idleTimerDisabled` *disables* auto locking, quite the reverse of what you described in the question.

Comment: friend, making the timer value true or false after some time delays I can set the auto-Lock 'lock' or 'unlock' as per the selection of time.

Comment: OK. But notice that the auto-lock time depends on the user.

Comment: hey can we check the value of this user set auto-lock time?